# CodeIgniter disallowed characters using QUERY_STRING uri protocol

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, query-string, encodeuricomponent

I've been working on a project and been testing it on localhost as well as on a free web server, and it has worked perfectly. However when I got my own domain and web hosting service the site stopped working.

To make it work I had to change the RewriteRule to

```
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

and then setting

```
    $config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';
```

However, links like this one;

```
    http://www.mydomain.com/ajax/membersearch/anemail%40here.com
```

used to work, but now it returns a CI error saying "The URI you submitted has disallowed characters."

This worked perfectly before I had to change the RewriteRule and uri_protocol, so I'm wondering what is making it not work now, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to update your config.php file. Replace the default permitted characters setting  with the following line:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%\.\:_\+-,';
```

Comment: wait... % and . are in default... let me check on this

Comment: My assumption is that you may want to set the uri_protocol back to PATH_INFO - you can probably add ? and = into the permitted chars if you also need query strings, though i've never tried that with CI. Typically I don't need query string URI when using parameters.